# Dagger 2 Inject DialogUtils class in activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, dagger-2

I'm trying to inject my `DialogUtils` class that requires an **activity context** in its constructor into my `LoginActivity`. Below code is working but I'm just initializing `DialogUtils` and not injecting it.

DialogUtils.kt

```
class DialogUtils constructor(context: Context) {

    private val dialog: AlertDialog

    init {
        dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok) { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            .create()
    }

    fun showDialog(title: String, msg: String) {
        dialog.setTitle(title)
        dialog.setMessage(msg)
        dialog.show()
    }

    fun clear() {
        if (dialog.isShowing) {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    }

}
```

LoginActivity.kt

```
class LoginActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    private val loginViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
    }
    private lateinit var dialogUtils: DialogUtils

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        dialogUtils = DialogUtils(this)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        dialogUtils.clear()
    }

}
```

What I want to do is to `@Inject dialogUtils: DialogUtils` in my `LoginActivity` but for this I'll need activity context. How can I achieve this keeping in mind that `DialogUtils` is used in many activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a flaw in your design here, that has nothing to do with DI or Dagger even: It's that your `DialogUtils` class will use plain `AlertDialog`s instead of `DialogFragment`s. This means that dialogs generated by your class are not persistent on the screen (e.g. during activity restarts like when the device rotates) which gives a bad user experience.

So what I'd do instead is to write a custom `AlertDialogFragment` implementation that communicates via callbacks with it's host (which might be an `Activity` or a `Fragment`), meaning that your dialog fragment implementation looks in certain places if it finds a host that implements its callback and communicates back user actions (such as button clicks, etc.). This is some utility code I usually use in my projects for this purpose:

```
inline fun <reified T> Fragment.requireCallback(): T =
    findCallback() ?: error("No parent / target found or parent / target does not implement " + T::class.java)

inline fun <reified T> Fragment.findCallback(): T? {
    val callback: Any? = parentFragment ?: targetFragment ?: context
    return callback as? T
}
```

This could go into your `AlertDialogFragment` implementation like this:

```
class AlertDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var listener: Listener

    interface Listener {
        fun onDialogResult(requestCode: Int, result: AlertDialogResult)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        listener = requireCallback()
    }
    ...
}
```

Now when you instantiate your dialog in your parent `Activity` or `Fragment`, you just need to let this parent implement the `AlertDialogFragment.Listener` interface and you'd forward it's results to your `ViewModel` - and the nice thing is: this would work across activity restarts!

You might wonder whether you want to require the callback to be implemented on the host for each dialog; my personal rule is: for one-button dialogs that mainly confirm actions (like error dialogs) I don't require the callback to be present (i.e. use the plain `findCallback()`), while for special `DecisionDialogFragment` implementations that have more than one button to click I make the callback usually required, so my app actually crashes if the callback is not implemented on the host as this usually means a missing piece of code on my side.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `LoginActivity` (and all the others) as `Context` in a module, then add that module to the component you use to inject your Activity. Your utils can then inject/use the `Context` without problems.

e.g. in your LoginModule

```
@Module
interface LoginModule {
  @Binds
  bindActivityContext(activity: Context) : Context
}
```

...then add the module to your component...

```
@(Sub)Component(modules=[..., LoginModule::class])
interface LoginComponent {
  // ...
}
```

If you already bound a context you can bind another one using `@Named(..)` or any other qualifier annotation. You could also bind it as `Activity` directly.